# when called Securityutils.getsubject().hasRole("any") with multipe realms, for a nonexistent role throws an exception

Tags: java, shiro

I created two realms for authentication in apache shiro, but when i tried to call hasRole("any") it throws the following exception (if the role exists, it returns true):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.shiro.subject.SimplePrincipalCollection cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.ws.shiro.RedisStringSerializer.serialize(RedisStringSerializer.java:13) ~[shiro-redis-3.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.crazycake.shiro.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:79) ~[shiro-redis-3.2.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm.getAuthorizationInfo(AuthorizingRealm.java:328) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm.hasRole(AuthorizingRealm.java:573) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.authz.ModularRealmAuthorizer.hasRole(ModularRealmAuthorizer.java:374) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthorizingSecurityManager.hasRole(AuthorizingSecurityManager.java:153) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.hasRole(DelegatingSubject.java:224) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at com.ws.user.login.LoginResource.login(LoginResource.java:65) ~[main/:?]
```

the SHIRO.INI is:

```
# =======================
# Shiro INI configuration
# =======================


## Using Sha256 cryptography
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1024
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
dbRealm = com.ws.user.realm.DataBaseRealm
dbRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher

credentialsMatcherToken = com.ws.user.realm.CustomCredentialMatcherToken
credentialsMatcherToken.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
credentialsMatcherToken.hashIterations = 1024
credentialsMatcherToken.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false

tokenRealm = com.ws.user.realm.DataBaseBearerRealm
tokenRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcherToken

securityManager.realms = $dbRealm, $tokenRealm

#redisManager
redisManager = com.ws.shiro.RedisManager
redisManager.host = <THERE IS A HOST HERE>
redisManager.port = 6379
redisManager.expire = 1000
redisManager.timeout = 0

#============redisSessionDAO=============
redisSessionDAO = com.ws.shiro.RedisSessionDAO
redisSessionDAO.redisManager = $redisManager
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $redisSessionDAO
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

#============redisCacheManager===========
cacheManager = com.ws.shiro.RedisCacheManager
cacheManager.redisManager = $redisManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

It seems to be some config, cause when debugging, it goes just for the actual token that I tried to authenticate, but in the class ModularRealmAuthorizer, method hasRole, it was called twice, one each realm, the first was ok, and then in the second Realm, it throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I forgot to override the method getAuthorizationCacheKey, in one of my custom realm.